# React app gets broken after fetch() request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

So I'm with an issue in my react app that I can't seem to solve, already for 2 days. I have my routes defined in my App.js file, with loader methods. One of these routes (/myreputation) has a loader method that executes a fetch request to my backend server. The problem is, whenever I refresh the page (after the request is made), my application gets broken, as if the css gets all messed up. This is the App.js file where I define the loader method (getReputationLoader):

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
path: "/",
element: <RootLayout />,
errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
children: [
  { path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
  { path: "/home", element: <HomePage /> },
  { path: "/help", element: <HelpPage /> },
  { path: "/signup", element: <SignupPage /> },
  { path: "/signin", element: <SigninPage /> },
  { path: "/resetpwform", element: <ResetPasswordFormPage /> },
  { path: "/emailSent", element: <EmailSentPage /> },
  { path: "/setnewpassword", element: <SetPasswordPage /> },
  { path: "/resetsuccessful", element: <SuccessfulResetPage /> },
  { path: "/editprofile", element: <EditPage />, loader: checkAuthLoader },
  {
    path: "/myreputation",
    element: <ReputationPage />,
    loader: getReputationLoader,
  },
  {
    path: "/makeclassification",
    element: <MakeClassificationPage />,
    loader: checkAuthLoader,
  },
  {
    path: "/codeanalysis",
    element: <CodeSnippetAnalysisPage />,
    loader: checkAuthLoader,
  },
  {
    path: " /myclassifications",
    element: <MyClassificationsPage />,
    loader: checkAuthLoader,
  },
  { path: "/overview", element: <OverviewPage /> },
  { path: "/error", element: <ErrorPage /> },
  { path: "/unauthorized", element: <UnauthorizedPage /> },
  { path: "/tests", element: <Tests /> },
],
},
]);

function App() {
  const [isDarkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const token = getAuthToken();
  const tokenDuration = getTokenDuration();
  useEffect(() => {
     if (token) {
     setIsLoggedIn(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("tokenExpirationDate");
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  }, tokenDuration); //7 days token duration before expires - 604800000 in ms
}
}, [token, tokenDuration]);

 const themeHandler = () => {
   setDarkTheme((prev) => !prev);
   };

 const handleLogin = () => {
setIsLoggedIn(true);
};

   const handleLogout = () => {
   setIsLoggedIn(false);
 };

 const theme = isDarkTheme ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

return (
   <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
  <DarkThemeContext.Provider
    value={{
      handler: themeHandler,
    }}
  >
    <AuthenticationStatusContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
        loginHandler: handleLogin,
        logoutHandler: handleLogout,
      }}
    >
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles></GlobalStyles>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AuthenticationStatusContext.Provider>
  </DarkThemeContext.Provider>
</StyledEngineProvider>
 );
}
```

And this is the MyReputation page where I use the data fecthed alongside with the loader method:

```
 const ReputationPage = () => {
 const reputationData = useLoaderData();
 //console.log(reputationData);
 return (
<Fragment>
  <ReputationTable data={reputationData}></ReputationTable>
</Fragment>
 );
};

export async function getReputationLoader() {
//checkAuthLoader();
 const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
 const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
 const userId = decodedToken.unique_name;

 try {
   const response = await fetch(
  `https://localhost:7182/api/v1/users/reputation/${userId}`,
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    },
  }
);
console.log("AQUI 1");
if (!response.ok) {
  //throw new Error();
  return;
} else if (response.ok) {
  const responseInfo = await response.json();
  return responseInfo;
 }
  } catch (error) {
  redirect("/error");
  }
 }
```

I feel like the app is not rendering after that request. Whenever I don't use that loader (getReputationLoader) everything works just fine. I really can't find a solution to this. Thank you for your time.